# Hibernate caching using Criteria queries

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

So, my problem is I'm not sure whether my queries are being cached. The hibernate.xml that I have right now uses ehcache for the second level cache.

Right now this is my test code:

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Users.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", "777008"));

    Users user = (Users) criteria.uniqueResult();

    HibernateUtil.closeCurrentSession();

    Session anotherSession = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
    Criteria anotherCriteria = anotherSession.createCriteria(Users.class);
    anotherCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", "777008"));

    Users anotherUser = (Users) anotherCriteria.uniqueResult();
```

The `HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession()`method retrieves the current session in a `ThreadLocal` variable if it's available. If the session is null, then it creates one.

The `HibernateUtil.closeCurrentSession()` gets the session from the `ThreadLocal` variable and closes it if it's not null.

Whenever I run the code above (it's a JUnit test), I can only see one Hibernate log that SELECTS from the database. I was expecting there to be two since I'm not forcefully caching anything by using `Criteria.setCaching(true)`.

I believe that first level caches only exist within the session scope and second level caches are basically application caches. In the middle of the two `criteria.uniqueResult()` invocations above, I close the session.

My question is, why am I only seeing one Hibernate SELECT statement log? Shouldn't I be seeing two?

Also, when I go to my hibernate.xml and disable second level caching, the same output still appears which is what really confuses me alot.

Example of SELECT statement log that I see: `Hibernate: select this_.id as id8_0_, this_.nameas name8_0_, from users this_ where this_.id=?

EDIT: I tried a different approach this time. Please refer to the following code snippet below:

```
@Test
public void testCaching(){

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){


        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            logger.info("Retrieving user.");
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Users.class);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", "777008"));
            criteria.setCacheable(true); 

            Users user = (Users) criteria.uniqueResult();

        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Got it");
        }
        finally{
            HibernateUtil.closeCurrentSession();

        }
    }
}
```

So, now, every time the test invokes `Criteria.uniqueResult()`, it displays a Hibernate log. So now, what I'm concerned about is am I even caching anything? Second-level caching (ehcache) is enabled using this test.

EDIT 2: Okay so now, I sort of figured why it wasn't caching. Turns out that I had to put `<cache usage="read-write"/>` inside the `<class>` of my object's XML. However, I can't do that since other applications are using the XML as well. Is there anyway to enable caching only on your application?

Answer (score 0):

You see one query because the User object of id=777008 is already in the Hibernate context. Try to query using name field instead of @Id field and you should see two queries.

Also query caching can be already switched on globally in your cofiguration without you setting it on for the particular query.

Comment: So since it's already in the Hibernate context, does that mean that it's cached? Why should I used the name field? I can only query using the ID field. I can't really globally configure it to cache since I'm not allowed to. The hibernate.xml is being used by other apps as well.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that if you use the query that is not id based but some other property, you would see two queries. Yes, the recently objects are cached in the hibernate context, and id based search goes to that context first. So for example if you have some @OneToMany colleciton of users (unless you have batch fetching), then you will not see sql statements for all the users but only for those which have not been already in the context.

Comment: Hmmm.. you lost me at Hibernate context. I believe there's only two types of caching: first-level caching (session scope) and second-level caching (application scope). Which scope are you referring to? It can't be on the session scope since I close the session after I query for the first time. It might not be on the application scope since when i turned second-level caching in Hibernate, I still got the same  results :/

Comment: it will be context related to the sessionFactory (configuration) not the individual session (so I guess it is called application scope).

Comment: Okay. So I'll change the question instead and ask you, is there anyway to enable caching on a particular entity (through the SessionFactory perhaps?) because I can't change the current Hibernate configuration. ehcache is enabled in the config but the entity doesn't have the <cache> tag

Comment: I am using JPA api not hibernate native, so I cannot help you. Normally the caching is on be default and you need to make an efferot to have it off. As you just discoverred in your question. You can check hibernate API for session factory and configuration.